# How to solve mavens deployatend while using the mixin plugin

Tags: maven

I figgured out that mavens build extension deployatend has some problems to deploy if some modules using the odavid.mixin.plugin.

I get following message for all modules:

```
[INFO] Deploying module.xy at end
```

After last module in the reactor build was execute it should deploy but i get the same information - `"Deploying at end"`

By removing the part with the mixin.plugin it deploys successfully.

My maven verison is 3.2.5 and i use the maven.deploy.plugin 2.8.2.

I think it deppends on the merged effective-pom by the mixin, which cause a broken module counter so that the if clause cant reached at runtime (attached maven snipped).

Can someone confirm that problem and is there any solution before i try to bugfix that problem?

```
 boolean projectsReady = READYPROJECTSCOUNTER.incrementAndGet() == reactorProjects.size();
        if ( projectsReady )
        {
            synchronized ( DEPLOYREQUESTS )
            {
                while ( !DEPLOYREQUESTS.isEmpty() )
                {
                    ArtifactRepository repo = getDeploymentRepository( DEPLOYREQUESTS.get( 0 ) );
                    deployProject( getSession().getProjectBuildingRequest(), DEPLOYREQUESTS.remove( 0 ), repo );
                }
            }
        }
        else if ( addedDeployRequest )
        {
            getLog().info( "Deploying " + project.getGroupId() + ":" + project.getArtifactId() + ":"
                + project.getVersion() + " at end" );
        }
```

Comment: The `deployAtEnd` configuration is known that it will not always work with other plugins (having own life cycles) or extensions which will change that as well....You could try using the [maven-deployer-extension](https://github.com/khmarbaise/maven-deployer-extension) which will handle in a better way (testing phase). (But Maven 3.3.1+).

Comment: Thanks, i will have a look at it

Comment: @khmarbaise nice work, that extension solved my problem! thanks a lot

Comment: @khmarbaise Is there any possibility to deactivate the extension for single mvn builds?

Comment: Unfortunately at the moment not but you can file in an issue so may be I will enhance it...

Comment: @khmarbaise Ok, ty. My second problem is that artifacts are installedAtEnd to my local repo when i use your extension. But i will only deployAtEnd not installAtEnd, is this atm possible?

Comment: At the moment it is not possible to turn off such things...Apart from that what is the problem with Artifacts which are installed and afterwards deployed ?

Comment: my problem is, that some modules try to get artifacts from the local repo while the mvn build. so atm they fetch old artifacts from the last successful build. but i get a workaround.